# Dynamically cutting shapefiles based on an eliptical or polygonal form

Tags: shapefile, pyshp

I have been trying to cut a shapefile in small parts in order to reduce the processing of the graph created based on that map.
I did find the ogr2ogr clipsrc option however, as far as i know, that one uses only a bounding box which is ok, but still includes unnecessary data that i want to get rid off.

Basically i need to cut  the shapefile in an elliptical form and that ellipse would have the major axis determined by the 2 points that i would insert. Is there any way i can accomplish that?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways you can accomplish that.

You can use ogr2ogr clipsrc if you have your ellipse as a shapefile:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc ellipse.shp output.shp input.shp
```

And since you tagged this question with pyshp, you can also use that.  The code below demonstrates the concept you mentioned using an ellipse and randomly-generated points.  If you are trying to clip a line or polygon, then no problem, just drill down to the points within each shape and test them for inclusion in the ellipse.

In the example, we work on abstract points and then dump everything to shapefiles at the end.  Then we read one of the shapefiles we created to demonstrate reading points.

The output shapefiles produce something similar to this graphic. Red dots are excluded and blue dots are included in the yellow ellipse.

[image]

```py
import math
import random
import shapefile          

# Source points to clip
points = []

# Create random source points
for i in range(100):
    x = random.randrange(5,40)
    y = random.randrange(2,30)
    points.append((x,y))

# Major axis min point (x,y)
major_min = (10,10)
# Major axis max point (x,y)
major_max = (20,15)
# Angle from center
theta = 0
# Radius
r = (major_max[0] - major_min[0]) / 2
# Center x
cx = major_min[0] + r
# Center y
cy = major_min[1] + r
# Amount to add to theta on each loop
step = 1
# Scale by which to "squash" ellipse:
# < 1 = wider than tall, > 1 = taller than wide
# 1 = circle
s = 1.2

# Ellipse points
ellipse = []

# Create the points in the ellipse
for i in range(360):
    rad = math.radians(theta)
    x = cx + r * math.cos(rad)
    y = cy - s * r * math.sin(rad)
    ellipse.append([x,y])
    theta += step
ellipse.append(ellipse[0])

# Point-in-Polygon ray-casting algorithm
def pip(x,y,poly):
   # check if point is a vertex
   if (x,y) in poly: return True
   # check if point is on a boundary.
   # Delete this for loop to include
   # only points in the polygon.
   for i in range(len(poly)):
      p1 = None
      p2 = None
      if i==0:
         p1 = poly[0]
         p2 = poly[1]
      else:
         p1 = poly[i-1]
         p2 = poly[i]
      if p1[1] == p2[1] and p1[1] == y and x > min(p1[0], p2[0]) and x < max(p1[0], p2[0]):
         return True     
   n = len(poly)
   inside = False
   p1x,p1y = poly[0]
   for i in range(n+1):
      p2x,p2y = poly[i % n]
      if y > min(p1y,p2y):
         if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
            if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
               if p1y != p2y:
                  xints = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
               if p1x == p2x or x <= xints:
                  inside = not inside
      p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y
   if inside: return True
   else: return False

## Start testing points
## for inclusion in the ellipse.
## Points on the boundary
## are included

# discarded points
discard = []
# points we want to keep
select = []
for p in points:
    x,y = p
    if pip(x,y,ellipse):
        select.append(p)
    else: 
        discard.append(p)

# Quick Report        
print "Kept: %s points of %s" % (len(select),len(points))
print "Discarded: %s points of %s" % (len(discard),len(points))

# Ellipse to shapefile for visualization
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGON)
w.poly(parts=[ellipse])
w.field("OID", "C", "10")
w.record("1")
w.save("ellipse.shp")

# Discarded points to shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
w.field("XY", "C", "10")
for p in discard:
    x,y = p
    w.point(x,y)
    w.record("%s,%s" % (x,y))
w.save("discard.shp")

# Selected points to shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
w.field("XY", "C", "10")
for p in select:
    x,y = p
    w.point(x,y)
    w.record("%s,%s" % (x,y))
w.save("keep.shp")

# Next read the selected points from 
# the shapefile to demonstrate
# getting the points from a
# shapefile instead of randomly
# generating them.

# In pyshp, if you were testing
# polygons or lines, you would need
# to call the pip() function for all
# of the points within each polygon
# or line. 
r = shapefile.Reader("keep.shp")
points = []
for s in r.shapes():
    points.extend(s.points)
print
print "Points from shapefile:"
print points
```